# Xcode 5 - No Remotes Found

Tags: git, version-control, xcode5

Here are the steps:

1. Added a repo to beanstalkapp.
2. Added the repo from Preferences > Accounts in Xcode 5.
3. Created a new project with local git.
4. Selected Source Control > Push...

Xcode shows me "no remotes found".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably because you don't actually have a repository on Beanstalk. I don't think Xcode can create repositories for you on remote sites.

Comment: Checkout step 1: Added a repo to beanstalkapp. Clear enough.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode probably doesn't know that the remote belongs to your project. See if this works:

- Open your project in Xcode
- Head over to Source Control - Working Copies (your project) - Configure - Remotes.
  Can you see your remote there? If not, hit the plus sign at the bottom left and add your remote.
- If your project is showing, and you've verified the path, try Source Control - Push. You should see your remote(s) and a drop-down of branches.
- If instead you see "No Remotes", try rebooting Xcode.

Comment: Hmm, "Working Copies" is disabled on mine.  I certainly do have a local git repository, the Commit worked.  The Push is where I'm having an issue.

Comment: The words "Working Copies" will indeed be greyed out, but right underneath it you'll see your Project, probably followed by the word "master" or the name of your current branch. Hover over that. A fly-out menu opens, which will show you the "Configure" option. Select it and head over to "Remotes" (the second tab in the modal window). You can add a remote here. Push will only work if you have at least one Remote defined.

Comment: Brilliant @Jay Versluis!  So it's a 2 step process to configure: 1) Add the remote under Accounts, and 2) Add it under the Source Control / <Project> - <Branch> / Configure <Project>... dialog.

Comment: I haven't used remote repositories before, so I don't know if the menus changed in Xcode 6.  But at least in 6 (iOS 8, OS X 10.10), the menu structure is indicated in the previous comment.

Comment: Technically the remote is part of the Git repo. Xcode lets you add one to an existing repo, but if you've checked something out from a remote (via GitHub for Mac, or via the command line) and then simply add this repo to Xcode, then it will pick up the remote automatically too. This explains all about Git remotes - it's a good read: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Answer (score 1):

1 - go to source control tab (next to project navigator)

2 - right click on the master folder

3 - create remote on github...

Answer (score 0):

- Goto **Xcode** -> **Preferences** under Xcode menu
- Select **Accounts**
- Press "+" icon on the left-bottom corner, then press "**Add Repository...**"
- Add repository location in the text box, Click  Next.
- Give password if it asks.
- Now try to push again

Comment: Same problem on XCode 6.  I added the repository on Accounts (my repository is on Bitbucket), but when I pick Push, it shows "No remotes available" in the dialog.  Does anyone have any help?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to publish your repository first. You cannot push to a local repository.

I also had this problem but I realized I haven't published the current repository yet. This was the reason why there is no remote to be found.

1. Publish your git repository
2. Push from xcode